# How to Keep running VirualBox guest OS even when Host system logs off?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am new to Virtual Box. To complete one of the project I choose VirtualBox. I am running Kubuntu 64 bit OS on Virtual Box and Mac OS High Sierra as Host OS.
I am running a Perl Script in guest OS which will take more than 24 hours to finish. Everything looks fine until I observed this fact. Whenever host OS logs off or Screens locks or idle for some time, the script running in guest OS pauses and resumes only when the Host OS active again. I cannot turn on Host OS display for every 5 or 10 minutes. Please suggest me a way to keep running VirtualBox guest OS even host OS is idle or log off state.

Thank you

Comment: Does the script stop when the host logs off, or when it goes into sleep mode?

Comment: Script pauses when host OS becomes idle and resumes when host system active

Comment: Script is not dieing just stops execution

Comment: OK, does it stop execution immediately when the host logs off? I'm wondering whether the host is going to sleep.

Comment: Also, you might find [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76107/how-can-i-keep-my-mac-awake-and-locked) answer useful

Comment: No host is not going to sleep definitely. I disable sleep in host and even in guest too..I'll try to use that answer if it applicable for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking this Question

I found the answer..It lies in Guest OS. In power management, there is an option like after 5 minutes of inactivity system will go to either Screen lock or log off or Suspend. By default it was Suspend. Earlier I din't find check the option. Now I choose screen lock and it is working fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing and have found using the Amphetamine application will allow me to prevent the MacOS from sleeping whenever the VM is running.  Just have to set a trigger for the VM.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/q/5329) paying particular attention to the items in **bold**. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1341057/edit) so it follows the guidelines.